# Ruby rails model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

I have a model table, with attributes Seat_1, Seat_2, Seat_3.

I have a this method in the model:

```
def addplayer(seatno, playername)
    case seatno.to_i
    when 1
      self.Seat_1 = playername.to_s
    when 2
      self.Seat_2 = playername
    when 3
      self.Seat_3 = playername
end
```

What I'd really like is to make this method something like this

```
def addplayer(seatno, playername)
    self.Seat_"#{seatno}" = playername
end
```

How can I write this, so the Seat_x is refering to the attribute - so I can avoid the 'case' way.

Comment: You could instead have array or hash `seats`. It seems to be much more appropriate data structure here. But if you insist, look up documentation on `public_send`

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev. having a hardcoded seat number in the method is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`#send` is generally what to use when you want to call a method dynamically, specifying the name at runtime. In your case this could work:

```
def addplayer(seatno, playername)
  send("Seat_#{seatno}=", playername)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use `write_attribute` method

```
def addplayer(seatno, playername)
  write_attribute("Seat_#{ seatno }", playername)
end
```